# Labeling SetterBar in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, labeling

This is the form of my list

```
list1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
list2 = {{5, 6}, {7, 8}};
list = {{list1, list2}};
```

I want to plot list1 and list2 in a ListPlot with Manipulate like this

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[list[[1,count]],PlotRange->{{0,10},All}],{count,{1,2->"Label 2"}}]
```

This works perfectly well. However if I want to label the SetterBar 1, too, like this

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[list[[1,count]],PlotRange->{{0,10},All}],{count,{1->"Label 1",2->"Label 2"}}]
```

There always occures the error

Part::pspec: Part specification 1->Label 2 is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

edit: I can't figure out how to solve this problem. I hope I posted this correctly, this is the first question I ask in this marvelous forum.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to MMA.SE! It's good to see someone post a nice first questions (with formatted and working code snippets).

Answer (score 7):

Give `count` an initial condition, and you're good to go.

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[list[[1, count]], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}], {{count, 1}, {1 -> "Label 1", 2 -> "Label 2"}},
   SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Without it, `Manipulate` tries to initialize the plot with a part specification of `1->"Label 1"` which of course, it can't do. With the initial condition, an integer is present, and `Manipulate` can go about its business of displaying `list[[1,1]]` first.